# Weird ASP.net error that disappears on its own in a while

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.net application that I'm running which works just fine, but sometimes I get the following error. And it resolves by itself too by just refreshing the page OR saving the page that's giving the error and then refreshing it. The error is :

> Server Error in '/PinWW' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in
>   this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends
>   the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 16:  Line 17:  Line 18: public partial class LoginPage :
>   System.Web.UI.Page  Line 19: { Line 20:     private String connString
>   = "Data Source=DEVELOPMENT;Initial catalog=pin;uid=sa;Password=pass";

Cam anyone tell me WHY is this happening? I'm not changing anything on the page when it shows and error before saving it again and refreshing it when it works.